# How Does A 5D Mk3 Generate The Histogram It Displays In Live View?

Tags: sensor, canon-5d-mark-iii, histogram

What is happening under the hood when a 5D Mk3 displays a histogram (luminance or RGB)? What exactly is the data it uses (raw sensor data, jpeg or something else)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The majority of cameras use the JPEG preview (with picture styles applied) embedded in a RAW file as the source data for the histogram and blinkies. In other words, it's just using what's sent to your LCD display for review. This is probably due to limited processor load and data paths, and is a cause for complaint among photographers--that the data they're seeing represented is based on after-compression data of roughly 1/10th of the image.  You may actually have more latitude on either end of the scale with RAW files.

The closest you might be able to get to true representation of the histogram of your RAW file is to use the Magic Lantern firmware add-on and enable RAW histograms.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that most cameras use the JPEG preview to generate the histogram? Your post makes it clear that this is plausible but it would be nice to have something more concrete.

Comment: If you turn on blinkies and then compare to the raw later (i.e. In LR) you'll find the raw has A LOT of headroom left that is not visible in the preview. This is enough to convince me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The knowledge that in camera histograms are based on embedded jpeg previews is so well known that asking for documentation is about like asking someone for documentation that "a" is the first letter in the English alphabet.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: http://ronbigelow.com/articles/camera-histogram/camera-histogram.htm, http://www.ppmag.com/web-exclusives/2007/12/what-is-a-histogram-and-how-do.html, etc. lots of different internet threads dating back to 2005 :), and just comparing the histogram on the back of the camera to what you see in DPP or ACR from a RAW file. Most of us have experienced the additional headroom in RAW the camera histogram says isn't there.

Comment: @MichaelClark This kind of statement is completely pointless if you don't back it up with sources. And being condescending isn't impressing anyone.

Comment: @inkista Thanks for the link. You are correct that it is obvious when testing and even more obvious when comparing Canon's own histogram with the histogram generated by magic lantern from RAW data. However I would still like to see some kind of reference specific to the 5D Mk3. It seems strange that even if my settings only allow for generation of a full-resolution RAW image (no jpegs) it is still generating and analysing a jpeg for each frame of Live View data to generate the histogram. I'm interested in this process - how often is it resampling and is it using a scaled-down image.

Comment: @Pedr, remember that on-camera histograms are expected to be delivered live (in liveview), as well as instantaneously upon image display. Taking all 22MP of RAW data and crunching it into a histogram could lead to a delay. Even ML isn't using the full 22MP (just the video feed data, iirc) to generate their RAW histogram.